# Are Black Widow and Hawkeye an "item"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

I believe it is hinted at in the first Avengers movie that Hawkeye and Black Widow are going to have (or currently have) a *thing* but in the new Captain America movie, Black Widow and Captain America are hanging out together and things seem to be getting a bit steamy between them.

I was curious if anyone would like to clear this up, I always thought Captain America's love interest was Sharon Carter, the niece of Peggy Carter (who he'd known before his accident and subsequent freezing).

Comment: In the first scene with Cap and Natasha in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* (aboard the plane), Natasha is specifically trying to get Steve to ask out another woman. Not confirmation, but indicative that they are not "an item".

Comment: Thank you. I missed the first 10 minutes of the movie -I think I saw the preview including that scene.- But I was referring to that look they gave each other at the end of the movie.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/Captain_America_and_Black_Widow.jpg

Comment: I was under the impression that there was an unspoken thing between Widow and Falcon.  But maybe that was just wishful thinking on my part.  This could get dangerously close to "shipping" territory.

Comment: I think the closest hint we get to a Black Widow/Hawkeye relationship in *Winter Soldier* is that small arrow necklace that she’s wearing.

Answer (score 20):

### Nope.

*Avengers: Age of Ultron* reveals that

> Hawkeye already has [a wife](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Laura_Barton) and kids.

> [image: Barton couple]

He and Black Widow are apparently just good friends.

Comment: On the other hand, it's heavily implied that Bruce Banner and Black Widow are an item complete with a discussion of how the Red Room training has rendered her sterile, and he has issues with transformation related to sex.

Comment: Apparently good friends to the point of being like siblings............and how much it hurt to lose one or the other (Endgame).........

Comment: However, like the questioner, I did get the impression from the first film that the writers intended to make Clint and Natasha an item (as they were in the comics); it seems likely to me that the writers changed their mind after the first film.

Answer (score 13):

In the comics, [Black Widow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Widow_%28Natalia_Romanova%29) and [Hawkeye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkeye_%28comics%29) were most definitely an "item." The two are introduced as lovers in the same [comic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Suspense), five issues apart, Black Widow was still working as a Soviet spy at the time, and Hawkeye was introduced as a villain.

> On the run, the naive Hawkeye met the Black Widow, a spy for the Soviet Union, with whom he fell in love. Blindly following the Black Widow, Hawkeye aided her attempts to steal technology developed by Tony Stark.

Later, Black Widow goes on to have relationships with several other male superheroes, notably Tony Stark, but her and Hawkeye have a continuing 'thing' between them. Hawkeye also pursues other relationships, most notably with [Mockingbird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockingbird_%28Marvel_Comics%29), whom he marries.

As far as the movies go, it is somewhat obvious that they have a connection, but it has been kept deliberately vague. This is possibly because Marvel is saving their relationship for a future *Avengers* or stand-alone film, or possibly because they have decided on a different direction.

While Captain America does have more than one love interest in the comics, Sharon Carter is always the main one, and I do not know of Black Widow and Captain America ever pursuing a relationship at any point.

Comment: Relevant: In the movie Next Avengers: Heroes of Tomorrow, Cap and Widow had a kid.

Answer (score 3):

In the comics, they do certainly have a thing. Here is an excerpt from [*Avengers Assemble: An Oral History of Earth's Mightiest Heroes*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0785158014) by Brian Michael Bendis (Marvel, 2012), which draws directly from the canon of the original comics, and not the movies:

> **Janet Van Dyne**: I think Clint Barton is still in love with the Black
> Widow. I think she's the great true love of his life. And I take
> nothing away of his ex-wife Bobbi. He loves her too. Without a doubt.

where Janet Van Dyne is the original Wasp, and a founding member of the (comics original) Avengers.

And to make things worse, shortly after the first big change in the Avengers team synthesis, with Hawkeye, Quicksilver, and Scarlet Witch as the new members:

> **Clint Barton**: And to make matters worse, I had a gigantic crush on
> Wanda Maximoff, the Scarlet Witch, just gigantic... and she was head
> over heels in love with Captain America. I don't know if he knew or
> couldn't tell or just wanted to keep it professional. I don't know.
> But I was staring at her, she was staring at him, her brother, Pietro,
> was staring at all of us, and if you add the Enchantress and Power Man
> and Doctor Doom or whatever the hell else was going on...
>
> **Steve Rogers**: Love is a very strong word. Nodoby was in love with
> anybody. Hawkeye likes to exaggerate.